# Writing text in python with $ character

Tags: python, markdown, special-characters

I am writing as markdown the following:

```
cost_1 = 28 [$/units/year]
cost_2 = 30 [$/units/year]
```

and when I print it, because the `"$"` is a special character, I am obtaining the following:

```
cost_1 = 28 [ //]2=30[ /units/year]
```

How should I write it in order to use the `"$"` as a regular character in the text?

Comment: Which Markdown processor are you using? `$` isn't a special character in [regular Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: Are you trying to write this in a code block or in regular text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing \ in the beginning of the character.

```
cost_1 = 28 [\$/units/year]
```